# Mongodb id on bulk insert performance

Tags: mongodb

I have a class/object that have a guid and i want to use that field as the _id object when it is saved to Mongodb. Is it possible to use other value instead of the ObjectId?

Is there any performance consideration when doing bulk insert when there is an _id field? Is _id an index? If i set the _id to different field, would it slow down the bulk insert? I'm inserting about 10 million records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

1. Yes. It **is** possible to use other types than `ObjectId`, including `GUID` that will be saved as `BinData`.
2. Yes, there are considerations. It's better if your `_id` is always increasing (like a growing number, or `ObjectId`) otherwise the index needs to rebuild itself more often. If you plan on using sharding, the `_id` should also be hashed evenly.
3. `_id` indeed has an **index** automatically.
4. It depends on the type you choose. See section 2.

**Conclusion**: It's better to keep using `ObjectId` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: I read that ObjectId is faster. Here is a link. https://github.com/Restuta/mongo.Guid-vs-ObjectId-performance

Comment: @iefpw: The link looks plausible. Have a question regarding your data though. Are you going to query your GUID? If no, then it's fine. But if yes, then you are probably also going to index your guid to speedup its queries. Further, if you are never going to query MonogoDB's _id then you are only adding an extra field in each of those 10 million docs and carrying a dead index weight which will be maintained at some expense. The quick insertion of 10 million docs will eventually lead to an overall slowing down.

Still, the assumption is that you won't use _id and will query your original guid.

Comment: I will be querying the GUID. Previously I had the autogenerated GUID in C# like `ObjectID Id { get; set; }` and I didn't assign any value to it and during the insertion the Id got a value by the driver or the Mongodb server. I also needed to create a separate index for the actual object GUID, which I will continue to do, since I need to query the object. I thought I could combine the two GUIDs, but it compromises bulk insert performance if I change Id to regular Guid. Maybe I need to think of using the ObjectID as my actual object GUID that I will query and remove the object GUID.

Comment: @iefpw if you can, that would be best.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you can use that field as the id. There is no mention of what API (if any) you are using for inserting the documents. So if you would do the insertion at the command line, the command would be:

```
db.collection.insert({_id : <BSONString_version_of_your_guid_value>, field1 : value1, ...});
```

It doesn't have to be BsonString. Change it to whatever Bson value is closest matching to your guid's original type (except the array type. Arrays aren't allowed as the value of _id field).

2) As far as i know, there **IS** effect on performance when `db.collection.insert` when you provide your own ids, especially in bulk, BUT if the id's are sorted etc., there shouldn't be a performance loss. The reason, i am quoting:

---

> The structure of index is a B-tree. ObjectIds have an excellent
>   insertion order as far as the index tree is concerned: they are always
>   increasing, meaning they are always inserted at the right edge of
>   B-tree. This, in turn, means that MongoDB only has to keep the right
>   edge of the B-Tree in memory.
>
> Conversely, a random value in the _id field means that _ids will be
>   inserted all over the tree. Then the machine must move a page of the
>   index into memory, update a tiny piece of it, then probably ignore it
>   until it slides out of memory again. This is less efficient.

```
                       :from the book `50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developers`
```

---

The tip's title says - "**Override _id when you have your own simple, unique id**." Clearly it is better to use your id if you have one **and** you don't need the properties of an ObjectId. And it is best if your ids are increasing for the reason stated above.

3) There is a default index on _id field by MongoDB.